# Software to analyze an MP3 file and determine its BPM

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, mp3

I'm building a personal running playlist. I managed to calculate the right BPM (beats per minute) for me through this article on LifeHacker. Now all I need to do is find which songs from my MP3 collection have it.

Are there any good (preferably free) software out there that can analyze the tempo of a song and output its BPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MixMeister BPM Analyzer](http://www.mixmeister.com/download-bpmanalyzer.php) (free) seems to do the job well, although it can't launch or play any audio files from its window.

[image]